# Getting cpu model name from node_cpu_info with prometheus query

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm using Grafana+Prometheus+node_exporter to monitor Linux servers. Grafana dashboard (1860) is great.

I want to see **cpu model** on the dashboard.
But node exporter does not have a such metric as model name is not a real metric.

The information exists in **node_cpu_info** metric. *(shown below)*

But **model_name** information is located in the "key" part, not at value part, so when i query this metric i got "1" as result.

So my question is: Is it possible to take only "model_name"=.. part from metrics and show it on the dashboard? *(Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6152 CPU @ 2.10GHz)*

sample metric:

`node_cpu_info{cachesize="30976 KB",core="0",cpu="0",family="6",microcode="0x200002c",model="85",model_name="Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6152 CPU @ 2.10GHz",package="0",stepping="4",vendor="GenuineIntel"} 1`

Comment: It's not clear what you're going to do with it. Do you want to display it on a dashboard?

Comment: Yes, i want to see the model name like number of cores on the dashboard. Thanks for comment, i'll update the question

Comment: Ok, that's easy. Wait a couple minutes, I'll write you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a relatively simple table with label values like this one:

[image: label table]

1. Create a new panel, select source, change format from `Time series` to `Table`, select `Table` visualisation, and enable `instant` mode:
   [image]
2. Open `Transform` tab, add two transforms in this order: 1) `Labels to fields`, 2) `Organize fields`. See the picture:
   [image]
3. Disable unnecessary fields and rename ones you'd like to see.

Comment: There is also an alternative way and more complicated way to draw a markdown-based table using dashboard variables https://i.imgur.com/tTK1WXb.png . Contrary to this one it works with single values, that is you need to ensure that there's only one label set (for 1 node).